# Struct with array for Alamofire responseDecodable

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm struggling to setup a struct correctly for Alamofire responseDecodable to be decoded.

My JSON return structure is:

```
{
“SESSIONID” : ”GUID”, 
“ISADMIN” : ”YES or NO”, 
“FNAME” : ”ABC”, 
“SNAME” : ”ABC”, 
“EMPNO” : ”ABC”, 
"SITES": [
    {
    "NAME": “MTN-ALICE LANE”,
    "WEBSITEAPPID": “SiteGUID”
    }
  ]
}
```

My Swift code is where the issue is under the array SITES. I know this because if I remove the SITES from my struct then the rest of the JSON response accordingly but without the SITES array.

```
struct ValidateUser: Decodable{
    
    let sessionId: String?
    let isAdmin: String?
    let fullName: String?
    let surname: String?
    let employNo: String?
    let siteNames: [UserSites]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sessionId  = "SESSIONID"
        case isAdmin    = "ISADMIN"
        case fullName   = "FNAME"
        case surname    = "SNAME"
        case employNo   = "EMPNO"
        case siteNames  = "SITES"
    }
}

struct UserSites: Decodable{
    
    let siteName: String?
    let siteId: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case siteName   = "NAME"
        case siteId     = "WEBSITEAPPID"
    }
}
```

I assume my error is how I've created struct UserSites but unsure.

Comment: What error do you get? The code looks fine btw

Comment: You are using ” instead of " in the posted json but I assume that is just an error you introduced when creating the sample.

Comment: "Response: failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: \"SITES\", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: \"No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \\\"SITES\\\", intValue: nil) (\\\"SITES\\\").\", underlyingError: nil)))))"

Comment: So SITES can be null then, make the property optional

Comment: How did I miss that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Missing option ? after let siteNames: [UserSites]

let siteNames: [UserSites]?